# How to create constructor to fill xmlelement and attribute?

Tags: c#, xml

I have complex class which I want to serialize to XML format using costum attributes. I am stucked at XMLelement which is List and I would like to generate new items with constructor, where I can fill attribute name and text value.

Now I have to create seperate objects and those I can add to the List. I want to simplify this.

class to be serialized:

```
        [XmlElement("Cfg")]
        public ElCfg Cfg = new ElCfg();

        public class ElCfg

        {
            [XmlAttribute("Name")]  public string CfgName { get; set; } = "Default";
            [XmlElement("Content")] public ElCont Content = new ElCont();
        }

        public class ElCont
        {
            [XmlAttribute("ver")]   public string ContentVer { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("Prop")]    public List<ElProp> Properties = new List<ElProp>();
        }

        public class ElProp
        {
            [XmlAttribute("Name")]
            public string PropertyName { get; set; }

            [XmlText]
            public string PropertyVal { get; set; }
        }
```

usage in main:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //build promotic object
            PromoticXML xmlDoc = new PromoticXML();
            xmlDoc.Cfg.Content.ContentVer = "80323";


            PromoticXML.ElProp prop1 = new PromoticXML.ElProp();
            prop1.PropertyName = "neco";
            prop1.PropertyVal = "necojineho";

            PromoticXML.ElProp prop2 = new PromoticXML.ElProp();
            prop2.PropertyName = "neco";
            prop2.PropertyVal = "necojineho";

            xmlDoc.Cfg.Content.Properties.Add(prop1);
            xmlDoc.Cfg.Content.Properties.Add(prop2);

            //serialize promotic object
            XmlWriterSettings xmlSet = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xmlSet.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            xmlSet.Indent = true;
            xmlSet.IndentChars = "    ";

            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PromoticXML));
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("promotic.xml", xmlSet))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, xmlDoc);
            }

            Process.Start("notepad.exe", "promotic.xml");
        }
```

What my goal is:

```
xmlDoc.Cfg.Content.Properties.Add(new PromoticXML.ElProp("someName", "someText"));
```

instead of:

```
PromoticXML.ElProp prop1 = new PromoticXML.ElProp();
prop1.PropertyName = "neco";
prop1.PropertyVal = "necojineho";


xmlDoc.Cfg.Content.Properties.Add(prop1);
```

Comment: You are getting two steps mixed up.  You first need to add data to the classes.  Then serialize the classes.  You do not want to add to the XML Document, instead add the data to the classes you made, then simply serialize the classes.

Comment: I didn't get your comment. I am trying to fill class different way and it's not working. Can you extend your idea please?

Comment: You are trying to add items to the xmlDoc.  You need to add to the prop1 object.